# Ant task to check version of composants installed on windows

Tags: ant

i am new to ant and i would like to write a task that checks the version of composants like postgresql, java, Mysql, apache, php ....etc which are installed on the server before doing an update.

I have tried using the the exec task like this:

```
<target name="getVersionPHP" description="getVersionPHP">
    <exec executable="cmd.exe" output="${php.dest}/version.txt">
        <arg value="php -version"/>
    </exec>
</target>
```

However, i am getting the windows version in the output file instead of the php version. Is this the correct way to do this or there is another way?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you have multiple arguments, you'll need to put them into separate `arg` elements with the `value` attribute. Alternatively, you can put them all in one `arg`, but you'll have to use the `line` attribute instead.

Secondly, to insure proper execution on Windows machines, you'll need to add the `/c` arg at the beginning. See https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html

So:

```
<target name="getVersionPHP">
    <exec executable="cmd" output="${php.dest}/version.txt">
        <arg value="/c" />
        <arg value="php" />
        <arg value="-version" />
    </exec>
</target>
```

=== OR ===

```
<target name="getVersionPHP">
    <exec executable="cmd" output="${php.dest}/version.txt">
        <arg line="/c php -version" />
    </exec>
</target>
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your help, it works

Comment: @mandymakore Glad to hear it worked! If possible, could you mark this as the accepted answer?